# How to tell which tier of Heir rune to equip?

Tags: bloodborne

How do I tell which version of the **Heir** rune is which tier (1,2,3)?  I have two of them (I assume tier 1 and 2) but both have the same description and summary effect (*More Blood Echoes from V.ATKs*).
The only difference is one looks more blurred than the other.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clarity of the rune seems to indicate the level.

There is a rune that has picture of all 3 levels:

[Anti-Clockwise Metamorphosis](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Anti-Clockwise+Metamorphosis)

It has the following screenshot distinguishing the 3 levels:

[image: Level 1]
[image: Level 2]
[image: Level 3]